# Renaming project in Eclipse and preserving Git files history

Tags: git, eclipse, stm32cubeide

I created a project named *project1* in Eclipse (STM32CubeIDE) and have initialized a Git repository using `git init`. I have made several commits to the repository.

I want to rename *project1* to *project2* within Eclipse, however, when I use the Eclipse interface to change the project name, Git treats the files as deleted from project1 and added to project2, which results changing the last commit message for every file within this directory.

Is it possible to use `git mv` after changing the directory name, or if there are any alternative approaches to rename the project while preserving the project files history in this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: In addition to what kutschkem says, Git tracks files, not folders. Did you do the moving of the files in a separate commit without any further changes? What is shown in the _History_ view after you did the commit? What you exactly mean by _"results changing the last commit message for every file within this directory"_?